# Filter an array inside an object inside an object inside in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
  {
    likes: [],
    _id: 5f254e21fd3e040640de38b2,
    content: 'try this',
    author: {
      posts: [Array],
      comments: [],
      images: [],
      followers: [Array],
      following: [],
      _id: 5f21cd54ef00270af6126df3,
      name: 'Octavian David',
      password: '$2b$10$kwqMFk/B.N2wNKC01D8Tt.KezQN3kFQyqXdEcfVizFWmL.HY2/uJe',
      email: 'xx.com',
      username: 'octaviandd',
      createdAt: '1596050772192',
      __v: 0
    },
    parentPost: {
      likes: [],
      comments: [Array],
      _id: 5f254e19fd3e040640de38b1,
      author: 5f21cd54ef00270af6126df3,
      description: 'asdqwdqwdqd',
      picture: 'urllink',
      createdAt: '1596280345466',
      __v: 0
    },
    createdAt: '1596280353464',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    likes: [],
    _id: 5f25527f1a0f870948f4a150,
    content: 'lets try again then',
    author: {
      posts: [Array],
      comments: [],
      images: [],
      followers: [Array],
      following: [],
      _id: 5f21cd54ef00270af6126df3,
      name: 'Octavian David',
      password: '$2b$10$kwqMFk/B.N2wNKC01D8Tt.KezQN3kFQyqXdEcfVizFWmL.HY2/uJe',
      email: 'xxxx.com',
      username: 'octaviandd',
      createdAt: '1596050772192',
      __v: 0
    },
    parentPost: {
      likes: [],
      comments: [Array],
      _id: 5f2552761a0f870948f4a14f,
      author: 5f21cd54ef00270af6126df3,
      description: 'try ths jow',
      picture: 'urllink',
      createdAt: '1596281462164',
      __v: 0
    },
    createdAt: '1596281471814',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

So this goes through a GraphQL resolver. I have a ID that comes from an input and what I want to do is to filter the array of objects.

So, I want to map through the array of objects, enter the parentPost property in each object and then get the parentPost._id and compare to my input so I can filter it. If the [Array].object.parentPost_id matches my input then I would like to return that whole object.

I'm thinking something along the lines object.

```
arrayOfObjects.map(object => object.parentPost._id.find(el => el === input))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess wont filter for two reasons: it maps the `arrayOfObjects` so will always return them all, and the `_id` is not an array so `.find()` wont do what you want.

My suggestion:

```js
arrayOfObjects.filter(object => object.parentPost._id === input);
```

`filter` returns a new array by going through all items and get only those that return a `true` in the condition. The `object.parentPost._id === input` just checks if the `_id` matches your `input`.